# PHP duplicate validation code not executing properly

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I was trying to prevent duplicate email entry but the code won't run "else" part . Code is supposed to be execute error.html when duplicate emails occurs means same email is on database already.

I tried to give a unique email and a duplicate email . both time same issue occurred, it redirects to error.html page

```
<?php
require 'db_connect.php';

$conn = Connect();//function is on db_connect file
$value_fname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$value_lname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$value_email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


$sql = "SELECT count(email) FROM inquiry WHERE email='$value_email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // duplicate entry found
header('Location: error.html');
$conn->close();
} else {
$query = "INSERT INTO `inquiry` (`fname`,`lname`, `email`, 
`time_stamp`) VALUES ('$value_fname','$value_lname', '$value_email', 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    header('Location: error.html');
    die("Couldn't enter data: " . $conn->error);
} else {
    $to = $value_email; // Send email to our user
    $subject = 'Signup | Examples'; // Give the email a subject
    $message = '
Hi ' . $value_fname . ',
Thanks for signing up!
Your email address has been recorded with us, you can now get
Latest information from us .

'; // Our message above including the link

    $headers = 'From:noreply@example.io' . "\r\n"; // Set from 
headers
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
    header('Location: success.html');

}

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Did you missing `$` in `email='value_email'`?

Comment: Added $value_email but still same issue

Comment: The `count()` query will always return 1 row. You need to fetch the result and look at the value if it's 0 or more.

Comment: Thanks Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count() will return one row in all cases you can compare the value of count in your if statement or remove count from the query. The second approach is simpler and in worst case scenario the query will return one row so the performance is almost the same.

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM inquiry WHERE email='$value_email'";
```

Comment: Thanks I was using double count . Thanks for help.